# ath10k wifi device doesn't work - firmware load failed (QCA9377)

Tags: wireless, 17.04, atheros

I'm on 17.04 on a new laptop that has a QCA9377 in it and it is a pain in the a**.

I found different methods online, like the git repo of kvalo or reinstalling linux-firmware, but neither worked, my `kern.log` still shows this:

```
Aug 11 16:55:01 NAME kernel: [    8.333012] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
Aug 11 16:55:01 NAME kernel: [    8.333216] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
Aug 11 16:55:01 NAME kernel: [    8.335573] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901
Aug 11 16:55:01 NAME kernel: [    8.335574] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
Aug 11 16:55:01 NAME kernel: [    8.335934] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
```

Any other ideas?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Aug 2017 17:16 CEST +0200

Booted last: 11 Aug 2017 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-32-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 12:10:06 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3801]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:0712 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           348160  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    28672  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              782336  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              602112  3 mac80211,ath,ath10k_core
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    16384  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.84  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 2003:f1:c3c0:6800:4323:fd58:3ada:87a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2003:f1:c3c0:6800:9de7:53eb:ed59:ddcd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::a07b:988e:9153:d0fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24480  bytes 17009411 (17.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23328  bytes 3168361 (3.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 362  bytes 27078 (27.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 362  bytes 27078 (27.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       971     1  0 16:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       8b84c544-e7e5-3e33-923b-4586f2d3abdc
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   8b84c544-e7e5-3e33-923b-4586f2d3abdc | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.178.84/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.178.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.178.84
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.178.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 756000
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 432000
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1503327311
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.178.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       next_server = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 864000
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2003:f1:c3c0:6800:9de7:53eb:ed59:ddcd/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2003:f1:c3c0:6800:4323:fd58:3ada:87a0/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::a07b:988e:9153:d0fe/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::3681:c4ff:fe0e:fec0
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2003:f1:c3c0:6800::/56, nh = fe80::3681:c4ff:fe0e:fec0, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2003:f1:c3c0:6800::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd00::3681:c4ff:fe0e:fec0
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fd00::3681:c4ff:fe0e:fec0
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:34:81:c4:e:fe:c0
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_unknown_86 = 20:3:0:f1:c3:c0:68:0:36:81:c4:ff:fe:e:fe:c0
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:3:98:d2:f5:bc:84:a1:a6:97:38:75:93:3:8c:6b:da

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-32-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     55269025DC0881FB8B580CD
depends:        ath10k_core
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     292EDB241D2AD284531545B
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4B8612B6FF71DD27AE8CE67
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     309C9ACED540FCAA1DE7422
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
rawmode: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    8.052488] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.052792] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    8.333012] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    8.333216] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    8.335573] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901
[    8.335574] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    8.335934] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[    8.403175] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[   10.198901] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   10.205749] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   10.205750] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   10.205751] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   10.205751] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   10.221876] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   10.247338] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: The third line of your paste shows that a suitable firmware file was found and loaded. There is something else wrong aside from firmware. I suggest that you give us a paste of the result of the wireless script so we may investigate further. Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your paste, we see:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I suggest that you blacklist the module:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: posting via wifi! it worked. what the hell was that?!

Comment: That was a hardware block in the kernel module. The command removed the module.

Comment: @schojo those firmware errors are normal as those files have never existed and likely only used in routers using the newer Qualcom chipsets